# Best way to populate a flat data in Redis cache

Tags: redis, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache, node-redis

I want to store 10 million flat string key-pair values that are non-relational to one another.

```
key1: one,
key2: two,
key3: three,
...
```

I am using a lambda function (which has a max memorySize of 3008MB and timeout of 15mins) to run a populate function to store these key-pair values.

The key-pair needs to be generated first before getting SET.

```
const createKeyPair = (num) => {
  // some methods
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i+=1) {
  const {key, value} = createKeyPair(i)
  redis.set(key, value, (err)=>{
    if (err) redis.quit(() => {
      error = err;
    }
  })
}
redis.quit(()=>{
  // some operation
})
```

However, this method took a huge memory and a long time. I saw that HSET has better performance but does it matter when the data is flat?

I also tried using pipelining from `ioredis` module and replace the above code as follow:

```
const pipeline = redis.pipeline();
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i+=1) {
  const {key, value} = createKeyPair(i);
  pipeline.set(key, value);
}
pipeline.exec((err, res) => {
  if (err) error = err;
  else if (res) response = res;
  redis.quit();
}
```

but the speed is still the same.

Comment: Did you try to run the code without inserting into redis? How was the time and memory use? Are you sure Redis is a bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I cant pre-generate the key pair values and they must be generated right before they are inserted into the cache. Therefore, bottleneck.

My solution was to create several clusters such that each Lambda only runs manageable quantities. In other words, create many Lambda functions with a master-slaves relationship.

The master will send the quantity target for each slave to work on.